# manually adding rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to test rows color changing in DataGridView, so i wrote that code:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Uno", "No" });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Due", "No" });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Tre", "Yes" });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Quattro", "No" });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Cinque", "Yes" });

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Yes")
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            else
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

So, there are five rows and two columns. But when i tried to change color, it gave me a NullReference exception, saying that row.Cells[1] values are null. What's wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is your error here "row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Erase "toString()" in your if and it is working.
Value is returning a string ;)</strike>

UPDATE:
Use this. It will cast the object into a string

```
 if ((string)row.Cells[1].Value == "Yes")
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            else
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) Maybe i was confused by compiler warning which said that i should cast cell value to string.)

Comment: I have managed to get rid of the error by casting the object into a string.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the color of `rows` of `DataGridView` you can do this in [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) and for your main issue is use the [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == "Yes")
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
        else
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your approach is you can't change the design of the row once they've been attached to the grid.

But to achieve what you want you can use the RowPrePaint event.

i.e. from one of my applications:

```
private void tSEventsDataGridView_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //create new CellStyle
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

        //if we have a value and that value is greater than the MaximumHoursWarning setting
        object cellValue = tSEventsDataGridView[eventTimeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value;
        if (cellValue is double
            && (double) cellValue > Timesheets.Properties.Settings.Default.MaximumHoursWarning)
            cellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 220, 220);  //change the color to light red
        else if (e.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
            cellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240);          //else keep the alternating background
        else
            cellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;

        //set the CellStyle for this row.
        tSEventsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = cellStyle;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was only a test program. I've just started my work with DataGriedView. So, in future i will enhance my program and overall approach. Thank you and other repliers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use check row.IsNewRow, like

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.IsNewRow)
      continue;
    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Yes")
      row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    else
      row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
```